# bootstrap modal recreate without reloading

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal, reload

The content of modal window is generated when page was load. 
Can I regenerate content of this modal window by JS without reloading page?

My modal window:

```
<div class="modal-team-NtSubstitutePlayers modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="list-of-players text-center">
                            <div class="list">
                                @foreach($team->players as $player)
                                    @if ($player->ntsubstitute && !$player->ntskipnextmatch)
                                        <a class="player_choose" id="player_id_substitute_{{$player->id}}">
                                            <div class="player">
                                                ....
                                            </div>
                                        </a>
                                    @endif
                                @endforeach
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Do you use bootstrap modals? Add the HTML code of your modal

Comment: Yes. Already add.

Comment: I mean something like $('#modal-team-NtSubstitutePlayers').reload() or $('#modal-team-NtSubstitutePlayers').recreate()

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**
Add an `ID` to the modal.

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal-team-NtSubstitutePlayers modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="list-of-players text-center">
                            <div class="list">
                                @foreach($team->players as $player)
                                    @if ($player->ntsubstitute && !$player->ntskipnextmatch)
                                        <a class="player_choose" id="player_id_substitute_{{$player->id}}">
                                            <div class="player">
                                                ....
                                            </div>
                                        </a>
                                    @endif
                                @endforeach
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
//Show the modal
$("#myModal").modal("show");

//Reload the modal content
var modalHtml = $("#myModal").html();
$("#myModal").html("");
$("#myModal").html(modalHtml);

//Hide the modal
$("#myModal").modal("hide");
```

Comment: But I don't want to show or hide modal window. I want to reload content of modal window without reloading page.

Comment: In that case you should dynamically add the HTML code from your JavaScript code. I see you render the initial HTML code from the server.